# Return $sample result as appended JSON key MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I perform a query to find one specific record by ID in MongoDB. It works fine, and returns me the following document:

```
{
   key1: "value1",
   key2: "value2"
}
```

Now I need to add to the returned JSON record the key "seeAlso".

This key will contain a sample of 3 other records in the same collection.

The final document should look like it:

```
{
   key1: "value1",
   key2: "value2",
   seeAlso: [
      {doc1},
      {doc2},
      {doc3},
   ]
}
```

The $sample I already know how to do. Gotta add the following to the pipeline:

```
  {
    '$sample': {
      'size': 10
    }
  }
```

What I don't know yet is how to store the result of this sample in the "seeAlso" key. Such key needs to be created at this point, it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: They're truly random, just need to belong to the same collection as the queried record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to do the `$sample` in a subpipeline. To leave out the original record, add a `$match` at the start of the subpipeline to leave out by `_id`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      key1: "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "$_id",
                "$$id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sample": {
            "size": 3
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "seeAlso"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-zIZLrRvX-y)

Comment: Would you know how to remove the main queried record from the "seeAlso" list?

Comment: The only downside here is the 'see also' may contain the document from the $match.  To avoid that, sample for 1 extra document and add a $match and $limit to the pipeline in the lookup.

Comment: @PedroRabbi updated the answer to add extra leaving out for the original document

Comment: I think it'd be better to do the sample and _then_ the match (depending on the size of the collection). This is because of the way sampling behaves. Getting the sampling from the unfiltered collection that is one document larger and then excluding it is probably going to perform better than excluding the single document from consideration and then sampling the rest

Comment: Bingo! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much, mates!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with $facet with stages:

- $facet with 2 pipelines:
  pipeline1: $match the single document
  pipeline2:

  - $sample to select the number of documents you want plus 1
  - $match to exclude the document selected in pipeline 1 (just in case)
  - $limit to return the number of documents you want
- $unwind pipeline1
- $project to add pipeline2 to a field in the document pipeline1
- $replaceRoot to make pipeline1 the top-level document

Comment: A consideration here is that this approach won't use indexes. Perhaps do the two pipelines first (using $unionWith for the second) and then apply a $facet to the result